# Apache derby multi-user control?

Tags: java, database, authentication, derby

Keeping it short all i want to achieve is preventing client applications to connect to a derby network server if that connection has already been made. I have figured this would  require some sort of verification on the network server but failed to find any methods in the NetworkServerControl docs, well i think i didn't.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me, but perhaps you're asking about using a connection pool, which is a library that manages your JDBC connections and makes new connections only when needed, re-using existing connections in most cases instead.

Try searching the web for "JDBC connection pool" and read about it, and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: yea sorry if it isnt clear. But simply I need a way to regulate user connections, for instance if "Dave" is connected through a client then no more clients "Dave" should be able to connect until the first connection is released. But will a connection pool be persistent with the server and not the client ? Because if every client declares a new pool then how would it obtain the users which are already connected ?